# How to add one more element into all array field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

```
var employees = [

    {
        name: "Praveen",
        dateofbirth: new Date("July 24, 1992"),
        gender: "Male",
        salary: 12000,
        city: "Salem"
    }, {
        name: "Divya",
        dateofbirth: new Date("July 21, 1994"),
        gender: "Female",
        salary: 13500.33,
        city: "Thirupur"
    }, {
        name: "Elangovan",
        dateofbirth: new Date("May 5, 1989"),
        gender: "Male",
        salary: 14050.45,
        city: "Namakkal"
    }, {
        name: "Abinaya",
        dateofbirth: new Date("August 21, 1991"),
        gender: "Female",
        salary: 15230.78,
        city: "Thirupur"
    }, {
        name: "Surendran",
        dateofbirth: new Date("July 3, 1993"),
        gender: "Male",
        salary: 16302.44,
        city: "vellur"
    }, {
        name: "Hindhuja",
        dateofbirth: new Date("November 05, 1995"),
        gender: "Female",
        salary: 17000.11,
        city: "Salem"
    }
]
```

This my code!!, My question is " How to add "SPOC :987654321" into all field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), then apply just the property with the value.

```js
var employees = [{ name: "Praveen", dateofbirth: new Date("July 24, 1992"), gender: "Male", salary: 12000, city: "Salem" }, { name: "Divya", dateofbirth: new Date("July 21, 1994"), gender: "Female", salary: 13500.33, city: "Thirupur" }, { name: "Elangovan", dateofbirth: new Date("May 5, 1989"), gender: "Male", salary: 14050.45, city: "Namakkal" }, { name: "Abinaya", dateofbirth: new Date("August 21, 1991"), gender: "Female", salary: 15230.78, city: "Thirupur" }, { name: "Surendran", dateofbirth: new Date("July 3, 1993"), gender: "Male", salary: 16302.44, city: "vellur" }, { name: "Hindhuja", dateofbirth: new Date("November 05, 1995"), gender: "Female", salary: 17000.11, city: "Salem" }];

employees.forEach(function (a) {
    a.SPOC = 987654321;
});

console.log(employees);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employees.map(function (a) {
   a['SPOC'] = 987654321;
});
```

use map method and add property.

Demo : https://jsbin.com/xofaka/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Please specify, `.map` will return new array and not update same array.

Answer (score 0):

```
employees.forEach(function(v, k) {
    v.SPOC = 987654321;
});
```

By using function(v, k) you have access to both the value and the key of the current object. More information on **.forEach()** is to  be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Please explain what and why you have changed. Just putting code is not enough

Comment: @Rajesh What do you mean, he changed `a` to `v` and also added unused index `k`. This is the best answer.

Comment: Changed what? This is a forEach loop that goes through the array and adds the element to each one of the objects as required.

Comment: Still the value of your answer is 0 since there was already better answer then the one you posted. You can improve it by deleting it altogether.

Comment: @Setily what I meant was, you should explain your approach. Why have you used `.forEach`, some sample reference link etc. We are here to help and share knowledge and not code for someone else. So an explanation will help not only to OP but to others that reads your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        employees .forEach(function (item) {
          addSpoc(item);
                 })


     function addSpoc(item) {

        for (var i = 0, len = item.length; i < len; i++) {
          item[i].spoc = "987654321";
          // or  item[i]["spoc"] = "987654321";
              }
```